# Can I JOIN table on the basis of the case statement in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, join

Can I JOIN the table on the basis of the case statement in PostgreSQL. I have written the one SQL in stored procedure into that I'm passing the one flag on that basis I want to jon the table. Please see the case statement,

```
JOIN lease_intervals li_active
    ON ( li_active.cid = l.cid AND l.id = li_active.lease_id AND
         l.active_lease_interval_id = li_active.id )
LEFT JOIN applications a
    ON ( a.cid = li.cid AND li.lease_id = a.lease_id AND
         a.lease_interval_id = li.id )
 **CASE
            WHEN pIsFromUI = TRUE
                       THEN JOIN property_integration_databases pid ON ( pid.cid = l.cid AND pid.property_id == l.property_id )
               JOIN integration_databases id ON ( id.id = pid.integration_database_id AND id.cid = pid.cid )
       ELSE
           1
END**
```

Please let me know is there any alternate solution for above.

Comment: Can you show the full query, in particualar if you are selecting from the optional two tables at the end of your join (which apparently you want to not be joined at all under certain conditions)?

Comment: Yes, I want to join the table if this flag pIsFromUI if true and this SQL in Stored procedure. Actually I got one solution to build the query in string then execute it.

Comment: You could also put `pIsFromUI` as part of the ON condition and then it would never search this table if `ON pIsFromUI = FALSE AND [some other conditions]`. After that put in `WHERE NOT pIsFromUI OR pid.cid IS NOT null`.

Answer (score 0):

```
join
lease_intervals li_active on
    li_active.cid = l.cid and l.id = li_active.lease_id and
    l.active_lease_interval_id = li_active.id 
left join
applications a on
    a.cid = li.cid and li.lease_id = a.lease_id and
    a.lease_interval_id = li.id
left join
property_integration_databases pid on
    pid.cid = l.cid and pid.property_id = l.property_id and pisfromui
left join
integration_databases id on
    id.id = pid.integration_database_id and id.cid = pid.cid and pisfromui
```